# Tengo este problema: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in... ¿alguna solucion?

Tags: php, xampp, php7

```
<?php

        $datos = array("idUsuario"=>"",
                       "idProducto"=>$infoproducto["id"]);

        $comentarios = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarComentariosPerfil($datos);
        $cantidad = 0;

        foreach ($comentarios as $key => $value){

            if($value["comentario"] != ""){

                $cantidad += count($value["id"]);

            }
        }

        ?>
```

Alguna alternativa, ya probé con otras versiones de php.

```
static public function ctrMostrarComentariosPerfil($datos){

    $tabla = "comentarios";

    $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlMostrarComentariosPerfil($tabla, $datos);

    return $respuesta;

}
static public function mdlMostrarComentariosPerfil($tabla, $datos){

    if($datos["idUsuario"] != ""){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario AND id_producto = :id_producto");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":id_usuario", $datos["idUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(":id_producto", $datos["idProducto"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();

    }else{

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE id_producto = :id_producto ORDER BY Rand()");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":id_producto", $datos["idProducto"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    }

    $stmt-> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que devuelve esta función? MostrarComentariosPerfil

Comment: @Serux Una variable respuesta del la petición al modelo.

Comment: Yo desde mi corta experiencia lo que haría sería hacer un var_dump($comentarios) y en función del valor que tuviera empezar a hacer la búsqueda del problema porque por lo que parece no es un array  y debería serlo. Por ejemplo podría ser que tuviera el valor de false , lo cual significaría un error en la consulta a la base de datos.

Comment: El mensaje de error parece indicar que lo que hay aquí `$value["id"]` no es un array, ni ningún otro objeto al que puedas aplicar `count`. Es muy probable que lo que necesites sea sumar el valor de `$cantidad`  al valor que viene en la clave `id` del objeto `$value`. Prueba a hacerlo así: **`$cantidad +=$value["id"];`** Para más detalles, lee lo que dice el Manual de PHP sobre **[`count`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php)** y a cuáles elementos de puede aplicar dicha función.

Comment: Amigo estoy llevando el mismo curso por favor si hayaste como solucionarlo porfavor compartelo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres es contar los comentarios no vacíos, el [count de php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) devuelve el numero de items de una array, prueba con esto:

```
<?php
    function tieneComentario($value)
    {
        return $value["comentario"] != "";
    }

    $datos = array("idUsuario"=>"",
                   "idProducto"=>$infoproducto["id"]);

    $comentarios = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarComentariosPerfil($datos);
    $cantidad = count(array_filter($comentarios, "tieneComentario"));



    ?>
```